# Where should be parameters used for output located in the function parameters list

Tags: c++, c, coding-style

I am trying to decide on a policy regarding the usage of function parameters for output in our C/C++ code.

It is clear to me that the policy should indicate that all parameters used for output should be grouped together either at the end or start of the function parameter list, but I am not sure there are any good reason to prefer either of these locations.

Do you know of any reason to prefer grouping them at the start or at the end?

Comment: For C++, I think it is best to try to avoid these kinds of output parameters altogether.  If you need to return multiple values, you can create a struct or a tuple and have that be your return type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just my personal opinion, but **if it reflects copy or assignment semantics,** then I prefer to put them to the beginning, just like string and certain stdio functions in the C standard library do:

```
strcpy(dest, src);
```

looks like

```
dest = src;
```

and

```
fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), file);
```

looks like

```
buf = contents_of(file);
```

**If**, however, for some reason **this is not the case,** then I like to organize things so that input comes first, then output, so then I put output arguments at the end of the argument list.

Answer (score 3):

Let me mention another point:

Input parameters can have default values. To use this feature, this (or these) parameter(s) nned to be at the end of a function's parameter list.
Therefore, and for the same reason stated by user529758 already, I also started to put output parameters at the beginning of the parameter list.

Answer (score 2):

There are two schools of thought, exemplified by different functions in the C library:

#### Assignment order

```
memmove(target, source, size);
```

#### Input then output

```
sscanf(source, format, &out1, &out2, &out3);
```

If there's more than one output, usually put them at the end.